# Fetching rows with a particular value of child Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, key-value

I'm working with Flutter and Firebase (Real-time database). There is some data stored in the db and I want to compare the email (child) of the parent and only want to display the parents containing that particular email. Currently, it is fetching all rows. I think fetching through key value pair would do the work. But I dont know the syntax and unable to find help regarding it. Please help me out.

```
void myfunc() {
    databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
    });
  }
```

[image: database screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
yourRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo('abs@abc.com');
```

Read [Query Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Comment: This is not a complete answer

Comment: I'm still struggling with the syntax. This should be in a loop or what?